# Reactjs not rendering to HTML in Ubuntu 14

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu-14.04

Hi I have followed the example here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html to create a reactjs app but the browser loads a blank page. When I check the source, the div with root tag has nothing in it when it is supposed to have the html code from the react component.

I followed the same example on my windows machine it worked without having to change any code.

Comment: Did you use `create-react-app` command or the `npm install --save react react-dom`?

Comment: You need to check browser console. May be there is any error cause.